# PowerShell script will run manually but not as scheduled task

Tags: powershell, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

This question has been asked before, but none of the answers work for me.  I've tried everything that has been suggested on both this forum and everywhere else and nothing has worked.

The Environment:  Windows 10 workstation.  This isn't being uploaded from a server, it's being uploaded from a workstation because I have to manually update the file daily.  This is also a temporary solution until we get the new system up and running.

The Problem:  I have a Powershell script that will run fine when launched manually, however, when I try to launch it through Task Scheduler, TS says the Last Run Result "The operation completed successfully (0x0)" but the file wasn't uploaded.  Now, when I run the script manually, a Powershell window will open while the script runs but nothing shows on the screen, then when the script is finished running, the window closes.  This window does not appear when the Task Scheduler runs the script - leading me to believe that TS is not really running the script.

What I've Tried:

- Changing the name of the user account running the task (myself, SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE*)
- Running Powershell from both C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
- Adding **-ExecutionPolicy Bypass** to the arguments box
- Adding the full path to the Start In box
- Creating it as a Basic Task and just Task
- Sitting on the warp engines and nursing them in spite of it being an unavailing and undignified position

I'm including the XML code for my task in case someone sees something in there that I may be missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2021-04-16T13:34:17.5511135</Date>
    <Author>(redacted)</Author>
    <URI>\Nightly Update Staff</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2021-04-16T17:05:00</StartBoundary>
      <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT30M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Monday />
          <Tuesday />
          <Wednesday />
          <Thursday />
          <Friday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-19</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>-ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\StaffUpload.ps1</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory>C:\Users\%username%\Desktop</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I hope I've provided enough information for someone to see what I may be doing wrong.

*NOTE - LOCAL SYSTEM gave me a Directory not found error

Comment: You said you've tried everything. Have you added a transcript to your script and logged what its doing? The problem is invariably in the script or the permissions to run or do what its doing. you souhld post the script not the task xml

Comment: No, I said I've tried everything that has been suggested.  None of the suggestions included a log, but they did ask for XML.  Perhaps you can tell me how to add a transcript to my script?

Comment: You haven't told us what the script does. Also, it's normal to not see the PowerShell window come up when it runs. It may run under your credentials, but not under your login session.

Comment: You may call [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.1) at the beginning of your script to log its actions.

Comment: Note that pseudo-accounts like Local System don't have a `C:\Users\%username%\ ` folder, so make sure your `WorkingDirectory` takes that into account. Make sure that the file paths for the stuff you're uploading all work properly as well in the context of whatever user is supposed to run the script. Your task looks fine otherwise and it is running - can you add the powershell script to your question instead of the task xml?

Comment: `Directory not found` means you are reading or writing to a path that does exist for you, but not for the user running the scheduled task. Are you using a mapped drive for the path or is the path inaccessible for that user?. If not a local path, use UNC notation `\\server\share\restofthepath`

Comment: Also, try adding `-File` to the arguments: `<Arguments>-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\StaffUpload.ps1'</Arguments>`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Task Scheduler doesn't like the file to be transferred to be on a drive that is not on the local machine.  Once I copied the file to a local directory, changed the PowerShell script to point to that copy of the file, it worked.